# Inserting into a database from a java GUI

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi can someone tell me whats wrong with my code. It inserts the package into my arrayList but it will not insert it into my DB. The code posted below will run each time the user presses the add button on the GUI Thanks in advance!

```
  //Add package
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("DD.MM.YYYY.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
    String name = nameInputTF.getText();
    String address = addressInputTF.getText();
    String city = cityInput.getText();
    String county = (String) countyCombo.getSelectedItem();
    String contact = contactInput.getText();
    String description = descriptionInput.getText();
    double price = Double.parseDouble(priceInput.getText());
    boolean prepaid = true || false;
    id++;

    //Adding packages to the list
    packages.add(new Package(id, time, name, address, city, county, contact, description, price, prepaid));

    //Method to display packages in the text field
    displayList();

    //Method to set all button visibility to false
    buttonsFalse();

    // Method that sets all text fields to blank
    fieldsBlank();

    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO packages VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        statement.setString(1, packIDInput.getText());
        statement.setString(2, arrivedInput.getText());
        statement.setString(3, nameInputTF.getText());
        statement.setString(4, addressInputTF.getText());
        statement.setString(5, contactInput.getText());
        statement.setString(6, priceInput.getText());
        statement.setString(7, countyCombo.getName());
        statement.setString(8, cityInput.getText());

        rs = statement.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(A2ZTransit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you use `fieldsBlank()` and afterwards when you create the query you try and get the data from the **fields**, even though you just cleared all your fields. You could try and use the variables which you declare at the beginning (e.g. `time`, `name`, etc.)

Comment: I am confused, where have i fields as blank?

Comment: Right before the try catch block you call the fieldsBlank () method, afterwards in the try catch block you get the value from the text fields(e.g. nameInputTF.getText()) but how I understand from the comment above the fieldsBlank() method the text fields will be empty

Comment: wow cant believe i didn't spot that! Thank you but i took out the method call and its still not adding to the DB

Comment: Try using statement.executeUpdate() instead of statement.executeQuery()

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I can notice here now:

1. `executeQuery` is for select statements. You should use `executeUpdate`.
2. There is a high likelihood that you've set one/all the input fields to blank before trying to get them in your `statement.setstring` calls. It's best to first read all the values into variables, like you started doing, and then use those variables later on in your code. e.g.

   ```
   statement.setString(3, name); 

   statement.setString(4, address); 

   statement.setString(5, contact);
   ```

btw, I ran the code on my machine after making the aforementioned changes, and it saved to database.

Full source code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int id = 0;

        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("DD.MM.YYYY.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
        String name = "Tobi";
        String address = "Ibari";
        String city = "Las Vegas";
        String county = "county 1";
        String contact = "asdaf@gmail.com";
        String description = "Whatever";
        double price = 5000.0;
        boolean prepaid = true || false;
        id++;

        //List<Package> packageList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Adding packages to the list
        //packages.add(new Package(id, time, name, address, city, county, contact, description, price, prepaid));

        try (Connection conn = getDBConnection()) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO packages VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            statement.setString(1, String.valueOf(id));
            statement.setString(2, "arrived");
            statement.setString(3, name);
            statement.setString(4, address);
            statement.setString(5, contact);
            statement.setString(6, String.valueOf(price));
            statement.setString(7, county);
            statement.setString(8, city);

            statement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Connection getDBConnection() {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/stackoverflow", "root", "mysql");
            return dbConnection;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return dbConnection;
    }
```

Comment: Hi i made changes like you suggested but still wont work

Comment: I even commented it all out and just tried to insert name and still no luck

Comment: Thank you for your help i will compare and surely be able to get it working!